# Unplugging a Phone Charger on Shabbat?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, muktzeh, phone, electricity

If a phone charger (or any electric adapter that is not connected to a device, for that matter) is plugged into an outlet, does unplugging it constitute any forbidden form of work, or is simply a 'muktzeh' issue? If it is a muktzeh issue, can it be unplugged and moved if the space is currently needed?

Comment: I don't know, but I imagine that it would also have to do with your reasons for unplugging the charger. If it is to save electricity (which, for most people = to save money) then that's something that needs to be factored into the answer as well.

Comment: I got a pesak from my LORP (which i intend to follow) but he's no physicist

Comment: What's a "LORP"?

Comment: @msh210 local orthodox rabinnical posek - usage ive learned from your site

Comment: I'm pretty sure HaRav Masliah Mazuz HY"D has Teshuva about this. BN BH I will check back asap.

Comment: @HachamGabriel do non-Morrocans follow his pesakim?

Comment: @Kidor some Tunisian/Jerba community follow his Pesakim. Most non-Morrocans follow Hacham Ovadia Shelti"a.

Comment: Kidor, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for bringing this interesting question! I look forward to seeing you around.

Answer (score 5):

If the charger has an indicator light it would obviously be forbidden as unplugging would extinguish it. Even if not, phone chargers [utilize electricity](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/7288) even when the phone is not plugged in. Consequently unplugging would interrupt the flow of electricity and would most probably be [forbidden](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12572/why-cant-electricity-be-manipulated-on-shabbat) on Shabbos under the general *minhag/uvdin dechol* prohibition of utilizing electricity.

[Those that follow the Chazon Ish would regard this as an Issur Deorasa of Soser. Menuchas Ahava 24:2, quoted [here](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Electricity_on_Shabbat) writes that since people regard electricity as fire, it is forbidden to terminate an electric current as this is perceived as extinguishing fire. [This](http://www.kipa.co.il/ask/show/27029-%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%90%D7%AA-%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%A2-%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA) answer rules that unplugging electrical devices is forbidden on Shabbos.]

Comment: Wouldn't that depend on the reason for forbidding electricity usage? The only one on that list that this might fall into is the minhag one, and in this case it's a melacha she'eina tzericha legufah, mekalkeil, and depending on the circumstances possibly a davar mitzva. Since it's not nikkar at all, it seems to me to be much more like the [Star-K certified electric ovens](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10899/759).

Comment: Who says utilizing energy = asur? Please source

Comment: @Kidor Utilizing energy indicates that there is a complete circuit inside even before you plug in your phone. Unplugging it is thus breaking a complete circuit and interrupting the electric current.

Comment: @DoubleAA so its assur acc to the Chazon Ish? What about everyone who is oser for reasons like bishul?

Comment: @Kidor I don't know of anyone who forbids all electricity usage because of bishul. See [the linked question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12572/why-cant-electricity-be-manipulated-on-shabbat) for more discussion about why most manipulation of electricity is forbidden.

Comment: Michoel: Even the Chazon Ish would say it's a derabanan because of melacha she'eina tzricha legufah, no? Your goal is to move the charger, not make an unplugged charger (whatever that means). Also I don't know of anyone who regards electricity as fire except some Jews with a simplified explanation for why they can't use cell phones on Shabbat.

Comment: @DoubleAA Sho'el Umeshiv, R Chaim Ozer in Achi Ezer...   1-2-4-5-7 in the linked answer shouldn't apply as far as I can see.

Comment: @Kidor Those are specifically regarding incandescent bulbs IIRC not all electricity usage.

Comment: @DoubleAA They are the widely-quoted teshuvot when dealing with electricity.

Comment: @DoubleAA Whenever you change how much electricity you use, somewhere there is a gas or coal power plant that changes how much fuel it burns. So by unplugging the charger you are causing a change in a fire. You might say that it's too indirect to count, I'm not sure. But most (i.e. other than *isolated* battery or solar) electricity usage is directly connected to fire usage.

Comment: @Ariel Can you agree to be sure that it isn't an issur deoraita? It's for sure grama, melacha sheina tzericha legufah, and a shinui. Besides, are you sure the fuel input systems are that sensitive? We're not talking a lot of current in a waiting charger.

Comment: Just to point out that the Rabbis on that site seem to treat electricity as a issur deoraita, so it is appropriate that you put it in the brackets at the end of your answer.

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't know if it's deoraita or not. But, yes fuel systems are that sensitive - they have to be, conservation of energy doesn't allow any other choice. (Even if they don't change the fuel as fast, the voltage would change, so you would cause lights and such to get brighter or dimmer - by a minuscule amount sure, but I don't believe there is a minimum shiur.)