# GE Shabbos / Yom Tov mode on ovens - Machlokes

Tags: halacha, shabbat, yom-tov, machlokes

In this question [How does Shabbos/Yom Tov mode on a stove work?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10899/how-does-shabbos-yom-tov-mode-on-a-stove-work) it discusses how the Shabbos / Yom Tov mode works. I have recently heard that there are Rabbis that do not allow using this mode. Does anyone know who is in favor and who is against?

Comment: The answers in the question you linked cite Rav Heineman b'shem Rav SZ Auerbach as an authority who's lenient and Rav Shlomo Miller as opposed.

Comment: @loewian: Is that it? Or is the lineup deeper?

Comment: I'm sure the lineup is deeper since it would depend on poskim's views of electricity and grama respectively in general. I don't know of an exhaustive list.

Comment: r'Moshe Feinstein only permitted these ovens for Yom Tov, not Shabbos. So...

Comment: Lots of sephardic poskim would allow the use of these ovens during yom tov

Answer (score 1):

The answers in the question you linked cite Rav Heineman b'shem Rav SZ Auerbach as an authority who's lenient and Rav Shlomo Miller as opposed. I believe Rav Nahum Rabinovitch of Maaleh Adumim has also said one can rely on Rav Heineman's leniency here (though I think generally he is reportedly not so convinced of the reasoning behind Tzomet's grama machines).

Comment: I should add that Rav Rabinovitch has a more lenient view of electricity on Shabbos in general, treating it more along the lines of uvda d'chol (See his Responsa Siach Nachum esp. with regard to converts in Israel who continue to use electricity on Shabbos).